# missing the return statement in the if statement which is in the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, bluej

The problem that's occurring is that the error is "missing return statement"; How do I go about solving this?. The actual point of the code is to add the balance of all the companions together as well as the balance, then see if it is enough for the holiday.
I have also declared another field variable called

```
private int every1nzBalance;

public boolean checkMoney(Holiday holiday) 
{



    // For each friend i.e in the list

    for(Friend friend:companions)
    {
        if(friend.getMoney()+ balance>=holiday.getPrice())
        {

         System.out.println("You including your friends have sufficient funds to pay for the"+holiday+" holiday.");

         return true;
        }

        else

        {
            System.out.println("Please ensure that you and your friends have sufficient amount of money for the holiday");

            return false;
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: What if `companions` is empty and `for` loop will not iterate even once? What value should be returned? How did you ensure it?

Comment: BTW executing `return` will move control flow out of your method, and also out of your loop. Since you have `return` in both `if/else` cases it means you will exit at first iteration which kind of defeats purpose of loop.

Comment: Companions is empty until filled by creating objects and using a pointer from the 'member' class which initially stores the array list companions. The value that should be returned is a boolean because it adds the 'members' balance with companions then if it is more than the holiday cost then it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. If the `for` does not have anything to iterate over (say the array is empty), then it  won't execute at all. You  need a default return statement at the end:

```
private int every1nzBalance;

public boolean checkMoney(Holiday holiday) {

if(companions == null) return false; //also default return

for(Friend friend : companions)
{
    if(friend.getMoney()+ balance>=holiday.getPrice())
    {

     System.out.println("You including your friends have sufficient funds to pay for the"+holiday+" holiday.");

     return true;
    }

    else

    {
        System.out.println("Please ensure that you and your friends have sufficient amount of money for the holiday");

        return false;
    }
  }
  return  false; //default return
}
```

Comment: Is that accessing the Arraylist companions correctly?

Comment: I do not know where the companions list is initialized, but this for will work so long as you  pass the companions list as a parameter or declare it within the class.

Comment: The companions ArrayList is declared in the same class. When i execute the code I get a Null pointer error

Comment: That means that you did not construct the array.

Comment: public void storeFriend(Friend friend) { if(companions == null) companions = new ArrayList<Friend>(); companions.add(friend); }